# Требуется совет по одной детали в программе по вычислению и выводу в таблицу значений x и y по графику

Tags: c++, функции

Всем доброго времени суток. Изначально задание звучит так:

> Вычислить и вывести на экран в виде таблицы значения функции, заданной графически на интервале от x начального до x конечного с шагом dx. Интервал и шаг задать таким образом, чтобы проверить все ветви программы. Таблицу снабдить заголовком и шапкой (скриншот задания прилагается).
>   [image: Я стер остальные элементы кривой (до них я сам дойду) и оставил самый простой кусок.]

В целом задание легкое и понятное, однако меня интересует одна деталь: каким образом можно задать условие в цикле для счетчика i, чтобы при введенном самим пользователем шаге dx (да, это не прописано в задании и я усложняю задание самому себе) оно работало корректно? Если в коде, допустим, условие продолжения цикла будет i < 4 (от -8 до -5, 4 шага), программа выстроит табличку
из 4 строк (логично), но если я введу шаг dx = 0.5, то i < 4 в условии уже не прокатит и таблица будет неполной. Собственно, вопрос - что нужно в таком случае ставить вместо i < 4, чтобы при любом значении dx программа работала корректно?

Код прилагается:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, dx;
    float y;
    cout << "Enter x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter dx: ";
    cin >> dx;

    cout << " ------------- \n";
    cout << " |  x  |  y  | \n";
    cout << " ------------- \n";

    for (int i = 0; ????  ; i++ )
        {
            if (((x >= -8) && (x <= -5)))
            {
                y = -3;
                cout << " |  "<< x <<"  |  "<< y <<"  |\n";
                cout << " ------------- \n";
                x = x + dx;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Проблемное место указано как "**????**". Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо цикл делать от минимального х до максимального с шагом dx. Тогда будет работать с любыми данными. Примерно так:

```
for (float x = -8.0; x < 5.0; x = x+dx)
```

Тогда и не понадобится проверка в if.

Comment: "но если я введу шаг dx = 0.5"

Comment: @Igor то что произойдёт?

Comment: бесконечный цикл

Comment: @Igor Почему? ()

Comment: @Igor а, ок, видимо float надо.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы введёте dx = 0.5, то всё сработает корректно

цикл указанный ниже (for (int x = -8; x < 5; x = x+dx))
проитерируется по значениям 
-8, -7.5, -7, -6.5, -6, -5.5, -5 .... 4.5, 5 (тут условие не удовлетворится и в цикл не зайдём)